# Difference between mysqlnd_qc vs SELECT SQL_CACHE

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there is a difference between the plugin mysqlnd_qc and the use of SQL_CACHE. I searched a lot, but I couldn't find a post or so where the difference is mentioned. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a difference?

**Yes.**

But you can't actually compare the two. **[mysqlnd_qc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-qc.php)** is a feature of PHP/Apache while **[SQL_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/query-cache-in-select.html)** is from MySQL itself. It will vary depends on your settings. In `SQL_CACHE` The query result is cached if it is cacheable and the value of the `query_cache_type` system variable is `ON` or `DEMAND` while  `mysqlnd_qc` on your PHP is *always enabled*.

Answer (score 1):

- mysqlnd_qc is for PHP and the cache on the client side (Could return stale data)!!
- SQL_CACHE: the cache is on the server side (Could be used by any clients).